# When sending SMS messages - contacts must have mobile phone set as primary

Tags: civisms

Is there a reason for this restriction or is this a bug or a new feature request to have it changed?

I expect SMS messages to be sent to a contact if at least one of their phone numbers is marked as a mobile phone number, even if it is not their primary phone. I suppose it might be confusing if they had more than one mobile number, but picking the first of several mobile numbers would seem preferable to simply not sending a message if no mobile number is picked.

Also - this restriction seems limited to sending SMS as an activity. I can still send a Mass SMS to contacts even if their primary number is not a mobile number.

Answer (score 1):

I tracked down the bug here:

https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18713

CiviCRM is suppose to send to your mobile number even if it is not the primary one.

Comment: Ah thanks for updating your own Q - looks like @Jon G is already helping out with that. Could make it into next release (4.7.10)

Comment: This regressed, but now has a test and will be fixed again in 5.8 (https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/384)